# What is the "linux-2.6.3x.x/include/asm-generic/' for?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

My os-book says that if you want to add a system call to the Linux kernel, edit the `linux-2.x/include/asm-i386/unistd.h`.

But the linux kernel's source structure seems to change a lot. In the `linux-2.6.34.1` version kernel source tree, I only find a `linux-2.6.34.1/include/asm-generic/unistd.h` and `linux-2.6.34.1/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h`.

It seems that editing the latter one make more sense.

My question is what the `/inlcude/asm-generic` is for? How can asm related code be generic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

asm-generic is a generic versions of functions usually coded in assembly, but coded in plain C, without any inline assembly. It's probably made for easy porting of the kernel to new platforms, and to keep platfom-independent common code in one place.

Comment: Do you mean: asm-generic is a generic versions of functions usually coded **NOT** in assembly, but coded in plain C